# Try - Catch block on YouTube AS3 API

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube-api

I have a problem with managing exceptions (try-catch) in YouTube ActionScript 3 API. Well, in some enterprises, the users don't have access to YouTube because it's locked by the firewall, and I need to control the exception.

The error that I have is: Error #2044: IOErrorEvent not controlled: text=Error #2035: Can't find URL address.

How can I control this exception?

Thank you guys of StackOverflow, you save me a lot of times with previously answered questions, now I need your help :)

(Sorry for my English if I have some gramatical or ortographical errors, I'm not native English speaker)

Comment: Hola Victor. Please show some code, build a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Victor, the AS3 API has been deprecated, so it's recommended that you use the [iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) instead if possible. Please see the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms#deprecation) for more information on deprecation.

Comment: Thank you BinaryZebra for your answer, it's my first question here. Well, I solved the problem using this line of code

_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, myFunction);

And in the function myFunction, I handle the error.

Dear friend @not_a_bot, I notice that the YouTube AS3 API will be disabled on January 26th 2016, but this project is only for a few weeks and I need to develop this tool on Flash AS3.